# SWT and Webstart on Mac

Tags: macos, swt, java-web-start

I'm trying to develop a UI using SWT and Java Webstart. As a starting point I've created a simple app that works fine with Windows and Linux, but fails to work on Mac. My test app is available [here](http://www.bcfantasy.com/webstart). There are also links to the jar files and class code.

Can anyone explain how to make this work on Mac?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Does it throw any Exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

See this [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288436). Your JNLP file is incorrect. Remove the line

```
<j2se version="1.5+"/>
```

from the first `<resources>` tag.

Specifying
`<j2se version="1.5+"/>` in the `<resources>` tag without any other attributes
is throwing off the JNLP parser and causing the later line `<j2se
version="1.5*" java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread -d32"/>` to be ignored. The two
lines end up referring to two separate JVMs, and the first specification is
'winning'. That spec has no VM arguments on it, so the JVM starts normally, and
the SWT is loaded on the wrong thread.